# Using VBScript in tandem with Chrome to fill out forms and download files

Tags: html, google-chrome, vbscript

I need to download a series of credit reports using chrome, has to be chrome because my company uses last pass and I don't actually know the password.  I also need to use VBScript with windows default libraries.  The script needs to click (and I counted) 2 links -> then a radial button -> then input into 2 text boxes -> select the 6th item in a dropdown list -> click a download button -> then copy a string from the page and rename the downloaded file based on that. This last part I think I could do with `windows.xmlhttp get` then parse it, but if there's a better way I'm looking for suggestions.

My knowledge of VBscript is ad hock at best, I've had to learn it on the fly on an as needed basis, frankly its a miracle some of the scripts i wrote work at all.

The only solutions I could think of was to use `WScript.SendKeys "{tab}"` and `WScript.SendKeys "{enter}"` a few dozen times, this works most of the time, but has no reaction capability and can't copy text from the page and rename it for me.  The page also doesn't always have the same number of buttons or links so my tab count will be off at times.  My other idea was to use `http post` and `http get` but I'm more or less completely in the dark about how those work

Comment: I've run into similar difficulties as you have trying to do this exercise, using SendKeys only, if you find another solution please share.  In the meantime I've "favorited" this question.  :-)

Comment: IMO WSH VBScript isn't the best tool to do what you need, take a look at some [extension for chrome browser automation](https://www.google.com/search?q=extension+for+chrome+browser+automation)

Comment: @omegastripes While I agree with you, there a certainty many better tools for this task,  I'm stuck using VBScript anyway.  I have permission to create things like scripts if i need to, but I don't have permission to modify things like the chrome install.

Comment: VBScript won't help you with Crome. Anyway you can start with JavaScript, open console and type your code (via developer tools, F12 key). If you need to download reports on regular basis, then you need to open console and paste js code each time, though.

Comment: I don't know JavaScript but I could learn, how would I use the console to do this though?  as far as i can tell I can only use one line of code at a time.